# Как ограничить доступ к файлам для пользователей, но не для хоста?

Tags: .htaccess

Пытаюсь запретить пользователям доступ к скриптам на сайте по прямой ссылке. Если в файле `.htaccess` написать следующий код, то это действительно сработает и пользователям доступа не будет предоставлено.

```
<FilesMatch ~ ".(php|htm|html|js)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Но это так же запрещает и моим скриптам взаимодействовать с файлами. Ajax-запросы выдают 500 ошибку и не могут получить результат из файлов. Пытался добавить условие блокировки (всем кроме моего хоста), но это тоже не сработало: `Allow from %{SERVER_ADDR}`, как и просто написать ip сервера вместо `%{SERVER_ADDR}`.

```
<FilesMatch ~ ".(php|htm|html|js)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Allow from %{SERVER_ADDR}
</FilesMatch>
```

Ранее уже задавали похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234258/9816116), но при попытке выполнить ajax уже с этим кодом в `.htaccess`, результата также нет, но ошибка теперь не 500, а 404.

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !%{SERVER_ADDR}[NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error404.html [L,R=404]
```

В файлах `.htaccess` не сильно разбираюсь, но хотел бы понять как разрешить эту проблему? Чтобы доступ к файлам в папке был только с моего хоста и только из моих скриптов?

Comment: Возможно ли такое реализовать или большинство решают это как-то иначе? Например, переадресовывая?